# How to determine maxima on the boundary with 'findpeaks' on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, max

As far as I can tell, the MATLAB function `findpeaks` searches for maxima in the interior of the data set. Now, this is problematic for me as some of my data have maxima only on the boundary,i.e. the first value of the array or the last value, thereby yielding empty sets after computing `findpeaks` and thus causing problems.

Hence my question is simply: can I include boundary points as potential output when utilising `findpeaks`?

Comment: mirror your data on the boundaries, and use findpeaks. You just need to properly account for the extra points when observing the results

Comment: @AnderBiguri What do you mean exactly by "mirror your data"?

Comment: Include a sample of starting points at the start and a sample of ending points at the end. I guess something like this may work. `y1 = [y(4:-1:2) y y(end-1:-1:end-3)]` `findpeaks(y1)` and then exclude the extra points from the graph